# Edit Audio: Delete a 6+2 channel audio to 2 Channel only

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, editor

So there are a lot of AVI files who have 2 audio files embedded. I want to remove the 6 channels and only keep 2 channels because i want it to play on my XBOX360. On windows this task is very easy as there are specific apps for this. 
Does Linux Ubuntu have these apps? If not, what can I do to make sure this happens and I get the result I want.

Answer (score 2):

Even when this question seems to be related to audio, you are referring to an AVI, which is indeed a video file.

However, transcodification can be done by several applications which features GUI and command line.

I prefer -of course- those which feature a GUI, of which I can mention: Mobile Media Converter (only for 32 bit systems), Transmaggedon, SoundConverter and many more.

SoundConverter (SoundKonverter also in KDE) will allow you to extract the audio from a video source.

Official Websites:

1. Mobile Media Converter -->
   http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.htm
2. Transmaggedon -->
   http://www.linuxrising.org/
3. SoundConverter -->
   http://soundconverter.berlios.de/

When transcoding, you can choose several parameters like: Audio and Video format, Audio and Video bitrate and a few more options (at least in the advanced options of Mobile Media Converter)

Comment: Everything you listed takes a lot of time. 
The AVI files i download via torrents (or mp4's) already have 2 files embedded. I just need to delete the 6 channel file and keep the 2 channel file inside so i can play it on my XBOX. Is there a software to do that?
I use this on my windows side. Its super fast.
http://www.videohelp.com/tools/MP4Muxer

Comment: I have spent a couple of hours trying to find an alternative for your software with no success. Also tried to make the software to work through Wine but didn't succeeded. I am sorry if I can't help you. I am sure somebody will have a good tip for you, it's about time, please be patience. I could suggest you more software for transcoding but I agree what you say: it will take lots of time.